# Missing required module after adding a framwork manually

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, frameworks

i am going to import a framework in our project provided by company but unfortunately after spending 3 days and searching a lot on internet and also applied all the techniques already suggested in the stack overflow i did not able to over come this issue.after adding the framework to the projects directory and adding it in the build setting still i am facing an error saying Missing required module hub
Please any one have any idea how to overcome this issue.any help would be appreciated.
following is my X Code setting with imported framework.

[image: Framework description]
[image: Linking binaries files]
[image: Error when module is imported]

Answer (score 0):

try this, Click on the file module from file navigator on the right check if its assigned to target from file inspector